# Why does my program executes in step-to-step but not in normal execution?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

The idea of my project is to build a probability tree on a repeated experiment with several possible outcomes.

This is quite a simple project, and I think I did it right. It's a basic tree building : there's a building recursive function that  determines node values and initializes children, and then build children.

Simplified code :

```
typedef struct Node {
    int depth;
    int noElements;
    float probability;
    struct Node *node0,*node1,*node4;
} Node;

void buildProbabilityTree(Node *node, int maxDepth) {
    node->child1=malloc(sizeof node->child1);
    //... set child1 values ...
    buildProbabilityTree(node->child1,maxDepth);

    node->child2=malloc(sizeof node->child2);
    //... set child2 values ...
    buildProbabilityTree(node->child2,maxDepth);

    node->child3=malloc(sizeof node->child3);
    //... set child3 values ...
    buildProbabilityTree(node->child3,maxDepth);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Node root={0,0,1,NULL,NULL,NULL};
    buildProbabilityTree(&root,3);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Full code (only 50 lines) http://pastie.org/private/cqiazmgp4bvexcidzlmutg

Problem is : it does not work!

I'm using Codeblock and GNU gcc compiler. When I run the step-to-step debug, program goes to the end with no problem. But when I build it without debugger, the program crashes when it reaches the "bottom" of the probability tree.

Anyone knows where that could come from ? A Code::Blocks option maybe ? A compiler issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to terminate your recursive function. Perhaps decrementing `maxDepth` and checking to see when you've run out of recursions may help

Comment: `sizeof(node->node0)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I understand that it's probably a typo but in the struct definition your refer to children as `node0` , `node1` e.t.c. while inside the recursive function it's `child1`, `child2` e.t.c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Decided to move comment to answer)

`sizeof(node->node0)` doesn't do what you think it does.  You just malloc'd the size of a pointer, not your struct.

Change your malloc calls to allocate `sizeof(Node)` (or `sizeof(*node->node0)` ... though I think the former is easier on the eyes).

Comment: Indeed, thank you... I still don't understand why it worked in step-by-step execution, but at least you solved my problem

Comment: The behavior was undefined since you were accessing memory you hadn't allocated. It just so happened that when you were using the debugger you were (un)lucky and it wasn't crashing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you only malloc(sizeof Node *). So you are only allocating memory for a pointer which is not enough!

You should malloc(sizeof Node).

Try to change malloc(sizeof node->childx) to malloc(sizeof *node->childx).